# How do you make a Discord bot delete the message and it says what you said after the prefix like ".say <text>" in Python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm just wondering, how do you make a Discord bot say something using a command like ".say " it deletes the message and then says the "" part. How do you do that in Python? I know how to do this in JavaScript, this is the code I use in Discord.JS:

```
const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'say')) {
    message.delete()
    var saytext = args.join(" ");
    message.channel.send(saytext)
    fs.appendFile("fbkbotlog.txt", `\n${ts} ${message.author.username} in ${message.guild.id} or ${message.guild.name} used say with text " ${saytext} "`)
}
```

I want to know how to do it in discord.py. I'm not really familiar with Discord.PY or even Python in general.

Note: I'm trying to use the Just-Some-Bots MusicBot code

Answer (score 3):

Basically the same thing:

**Using the message event listener** (very similar to your JS example)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.Client()
prefix = "/"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    args = message.content.split(" ")[1:]
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "say"):
        await bot.delete_message(message)
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, " ".join(args))

bot.run("token")
```

**Using the in-built command handler**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

prefix = "/"
bot = commands.Bot(prefix)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online")

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def say(ctx, *, mg = None):
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)

    if not mg: await bot.say("Please specify a message to send")
    else: await bot.say(mg)

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: Didn't work. I'm trying to edit the Just-Some-Bots MusicBot code for commands :P
My friend wants a say command on that code

Comment: What didn't work? o.o. Works for me. What your error message? @IndoHQBlu

Comment: It doesn't say anything

It just... Doesn't work at all....
Then again, this is the [Just-Some-Bots MusicBot code](https://github.com/Just-Some-Bots/MusicBot)

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord.ext

bot = commands.Bot(";")

@bot.event 
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.upper().startswith(";SAY"):
        args = message.content.split(" ")
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "%s" % (" ".join(args[1:])))
        await bot.delete_message(message)
```

Comment: You should explain how this is different (or better) than the existing response.